# How to implement HTTP 1.0 / 1.1 in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, network-programming, http-1.1, http-1.0

I wanted to know the best way to implement the following in ASP.NET. I have never used these directives so if you could kindly give me a sample code, It would be really helpful.

1. HTTP/1.0 Pragma header
2. HTTP/1.1 Cache - Control header
3. Backdated Expires Header

Comment: ASP.NET is hosted inside IIS, which already implements HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 and their cache-related HTTP headers. What is it you're trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: Where can I validate that in IIS? There was a security assessment done on the website we developed and the recommendations were as below: HTTP/1.0 Pragma Header was not used, HTTP:/1.1 Cache - Control header was set to private and lastly BackDated expires header was not used or set to -1. Where can I validate these items. I am new to ASP.NET especially these features. Please help me out. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned on your question, they are simply HTTP Headers. Some of these headers, for example `Cache-Control` were introduced with HTTP v1.1. Others were introduced since HTTP 1.0 (Pragma), etc.

All you need to do is add them to your Response via `Response.AddHeader("Key","value");`

For example:

```
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control","public");
```

**UPDATE**  Now that you provide more details...

I don't particularly see any security issues with not setting these headers on your response. What's the issue with no caching pages according to the auditing company? If anything, your website is **more secure** by not allowing browsers to cache your pages.

**Update 2** One way to define your pragma header on the markup is to have this:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Right after the opening `<head>` element of your `aspx` page. Similarly for all other headers.

Comment: Thanks lcarus, but I dont want to touch the code behind. Is there any way to implement it website wide? Like using web.config? or such.

Comment: @RAHULKATE yes, you can add them on the markup directly. But again, from a security stand point, I **strongly disagree** that setting them is a good idea. Not for nothing most financial institutions disable caching on their protected areas of their websites.

Comment: @RAHULKATE I hope your company didn't get audited by this company/individual: http://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants

Comment: Nope it wasnt that company. So, what I understand is that the most secure way of adding those headers is in the Code Behind. How do I add the Pragma header though? Can you please give me a small example to add the http/1.0 Pragma header?

Comment: @lcarus, I surely will read it over the weekend. Its a big thread, the preface is definitely interesting. Providing usernames and passwords in plain text??? Thats the biggest security threat....

Comment: @RAHULKATE I will explain how you can add the pragma header on the markup. Will go to a meeting and comeback

Comment: @lcarus, thanks a ton. I kind  of knew that approach, but then I will have to modify all the relevant .aspx pages. Is there any other way to do that, such that I do it once and it get applies across the web pages. If possible I would like to avoid to modify all the .aspx pages.

Comment: @RAHULKATE: I don't think there's a way to do it from the web.config but I could be wrong. Anyway, I would do it at the IIS level instead: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders